# How to add placeholder to text-field in servicenow service portal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, servicenow

I need to add placeholder to text field in catalog item under service portal on page load, I tried in catalog client script with jquery and angular/document but no success, And found that it's not supported any other alternate soln ?

**Catalog Client Script:**

```
function onLoad() {


    var elm = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("form-control"));
    //when I use angular I get this error:
```

> js_includes_sp.jsx?v=08-28-2017_0947&lp=Mon_Aug_28_11_44_06_PDT_2017&c=2_42:63808 (g_env) [SCRIPT:EXEC] Error while running Client Script "Placeholder
>   Script": TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of null.

```
 jQuery("#sp_formfield_IO:5cdafd764f02030007b03fb28110c70b").attr("placeholder","hello world");

   // if I use jquery or $jq I get below error
```

> (g_env) [SCRIPT:EXEC] Error while running Client Script "Placeholder
>   Script": TypeError: jQuery is not a function

```
}
```

**This is how html gets generated in servicenow:**

```
<span ng-switch-default="true" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngIf: !field.max_length || 256 > field.max_length -->
<input ng-model="field.stagedValue" ng-change="stagedValueChange()" 
maxlength="" autocomplete="off" name="IO:5cdafd764f02030007b03fb28110c70b" 
id="sp_formfield_IO:5cdafd764f02030007b03fb28110c70b" data-type="string" 
placeholder="" ng-if="!field.max_length || 256 > field.max_length" 
class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-
valid-maxlength" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" ng-
disabled="field.isReadonly()" aria-invalid="false"><!-- end ngIf: 
!field.max_length || 256 > field.max_length --><!-- ngIf: field.max_length 
>= 256 --></span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy,

The short answer is that there is no accepted way to do this in the Service Portal. This is because DOM manipulation is strictly blocked. 
However, the much-much-longer answer is that there is indeed a way to do this in Service Portal. I've written an article about it, which you can find [here](https://snprotips.com/blog/2017/7/21/how-to-enable-dom-manipulation-in-the-servicenow-service-portal).

You'll need the CatItemVariables Script Include from that post, which translates catalog variables into sys_ids. Since UI Scripts don't run on the Service Portal (even global ones, last I checked), you'll also need to create a UI Script and set it as a JS Include, which you include as part of the Theme for your Service Portal. 
(How to do this is detailed in the post.)

In the UI Script, you'll want to get the cat item variables using a REST request, and that Script Include.

---

There may also be a simpler way:

1. Set up the Script Include(s) mentioned in the article.
2. In an onLoad client script, use the Script Include to get the sys_IDs of all the variables associated with the catalog item by using GlideAjax to call the client-callable Script Include.
3. Use the **this** object as the stand-in for **window**, and remember that **document** is an element of **window**:

   this.document.getElementsByName('IO:' + itemVars['var_name'])[0];

In the above, **itemVars** is the variable name that contains the resulting catalog item variable objects, and **'var_name'** is the variable name.

It doesn't really do what you're looking for, but you might also consider the "placeholder text" dictionary field on the field's dictionary itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to just have a `placeholder` populated for a **Variable** without the need for it to be set dynamically, you can use the **Example Text** field in the variable itself.

[image]

This will populate as a `placeholder` in the form

[image]

Comment: I need dynamically to set placeholder

Comment: what is the type of the field you selected, I couldn't found example Text

Comment: In my example it's a Single Line of Text variable

Comment: My answer gives you the only way that it's possible to do this.